# Should I replace my damper motor?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, electric-motor, woodstove

I have a wood burning furnace that has a thermostat-controlled damper. The damper motor is mounted on the ceiling and has a lever arm with a long chain that raises and lowers the damper to let more air into the fire chamber.

Lately it seems like the damper is always closed, even when the thermostat is up high and the house is fairly cool. I pulled the cover off the motor housing and I was surprised to feel the body of the motor was hot-- not just warm, almost hot enough to burn my finger.

I'm assuming the motor has gone bad, but other than simply replacing it, is there anything I ought to check first? There's no obvious issue with the lever arm being blocked or otherwise damaged, and the damper swings freely, so it's not jammed on the damper end. I believe the motor is probably the original one from when my dad built the house about 40 years ago.

[image]

Comment: Motors can get quite warm, but burning hot is a bad sign(plus the 40 years).  Would get a new one.  As long as everything is moving easy and the motor is not in a hot zone/spot, probably just age.

Comment: Apply 24vac to it.  If it runs, it's good.